# How to get the context from Unit Test in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing

I am testing Unit Test for login but I got error when I tried to get the Context of that class.

Code:

```
@Test
    public void testLogin()
    {
        Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
        SessionManager ses=new SessionManager(context);// There I got null pointer exception
        hash=ses.getUserDetails();
        testName=hash.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
        testPass=hash.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);
    }
```

LogcatError:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mvp.Sharedprefernce.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:41)
    at app.test.contest.mvp.LoginUnitTest.testLogin(LoginUnitTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
```

Anyone solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with unit tests. When mocking object, you have to mock all interactions this mock has (it's methods too). Context is a very big object, therefore you must look for what is done with it.

In line `SessionManager.java:41` you are doing something with a `Context` that is forbidden by `Mockito`. Try looking for the answer there.

Comment: I created there context for   prefname and prefmode  in shared preference